# JQUERY 2 groups of radio buttons with labels - hidden radio buttons - 1 selected 1 doesn't get selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button, hidden-field, label

I have two sets of radio buttons. The idea is to use a label image and hide the radio buttons. When you click on the image the radio button should be selected. It works for the first group but it doesn't work for the second group. I commented out the css that hides the radio buttons so you can see that that the radio button from the second group doesn't get selected when you click on the label as it does in the first group.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/flaming_nonsense/rSBPJ/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup is the culprit:

- IDs must be unique
- Radio groups must have unique `name` attributes

```
 <div id="sites2">
    <input type="radio" name="site2" id="so2" value="stackoverflow" /><label for="so2"><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Stack Overflow" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="site2" id="sf2" value="serverfault" /><label for="sf2"><img src="http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico"alt="Server Fault" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="site2" id="su2" value="superuser" /><label for="su2"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rSBPJ/2/

Comment: I know this isn't good Stack Overflow practice to ask an additional question- but is there a good way to change the label image when the label is selected and switched back when it's deselected?

Comment: I voted - I would essentially be pasting the same code in a new question:P

Comment: @flaming_nonsense okay, please first try something to get better answers. good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the element should be unique. so change your HTML as follows

See the following link http://jsfiddle.net/bCLJZ/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you gave the same ids for the radio inputs of the second group as the radio inputs from the first group.

You have to give different ids for the radio inputs in the second group.